# Sub-header in jQuery Mobile?

Tags: jquery-mobile, popup

Creating a [jQuery Mobile popup](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/popup/index.html) with a [header](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/toolbars/docs-headers.html), the default works pretty good (I would like to address that non-round top-left corner some day):

```html
<div data-role="header">
  <h1>Useful Header</h1>
</div>
```

What is the proper way to **add a sub-header**? By sub-header, I mean text like the header, but smaller, probably with a smallish margin between the header and sub-header.

Google isn't much help, and this naive attempt fails:

```html
<div data-role="header">
  <h1>Useful Header</h1>
  <h6>Simple Sub-header</h6>
</div>
```

[image: Ugly sub-header]

Comment: jQuery Mobile has its limitations. If you want to achieve this, either override jqm css or create your own data-role.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to get the desired layout with CSS:

```html
<div data-role="header">
  <h1>Useful Header</h1>
  <p class="popup-subheader">Simple Sub-header</p>
</div>
```

```
.popup-subheader {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: -5px;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  font-size: smaller;
  font-weight: normal;
}
```